# Why are .exe files not generating output when called from batchfile within IAR?

Tags: batch-file, iar

I stumbled upon a strange issue where commandline executables (not build-ins!) do not generate any output, when invoked through a batch file in the Pre-Build or Post-Build actions of IAR Embedded Workbench 8.0 in Windows 10.

I did a simple test where the IAR Pre-Build action is configured to run `pre_build.bat`:

[image: Build Actions Configuration]

The batch file simply contains the following line:

```
git status > c:\some_specific_directory\status.txt 2>&1
```

When called from PowerShell or cmd the result is as expected: the output of `git status` is stored in status.txt. If git is invoked directly from IAR (without calling batch-file), git works as expected, too. If the batch file is invoked through the IAR pre-build actions, status.txt is empty.

This issue seems to affect any tools that are .exe files. So far, I have noticed this behaviour with `where`, `git`, `python`.

It also seems that these commands are opened in a new shell (the more commands in the batch-file, the more batch windows seem to quickly pop open and immediately close again).

Versions used:

- Windows 10 1703
- IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 8.20.1.14188
- git 2.13.2.windows.1

Comment: Maybe IAR doesn't find Git? Is it in PATH? Does it work if you put `git help > help.txt` directly in the pre-build field?

Comment: I actually edited the question to clarify that git called from within IAR works as expected. If a command invoked in the batch file could not be found, a corresponding error message will be displayed.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you could try `git help 1> help.txt 2> error.txt` to see if you get any extra information.

Comment: I tried that, but the git commands don't seem to return any errors.

Comment: It seems to be a cmd-issue unrelated to git, I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: does it not perhaps write the file in the directory where your executable is located? Just asking because it calls the exe with path, so it might write the file into that path as well.

Comment: so perhaps try something like `"command D:\some Dir\output.txt 2>&1"` or `cmd /c command D:\some Dir\output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks, but I know which file it writes to. In fact, the file is cleared whenever the script is called.

Comment: it is opening a second shell, the output is in that second shell and not writing back to the shell where it is called from.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Is there any way this can be prevented?

Comment: I'm in the exact same circle of hell, @moktor. And it can't be worked-around with Makefile targets without building an entire redundant Makefile for IAR.

Comment: @ScottS: The solution we ended up with was creating a command line tool that takes a command and it's arguments and will execute them through the Windows API in a new console...

Comment: @moktor: Thanks, that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

From: [IAR Tech Note Build Actions](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/ide/build-actions-pre-build-and-post-build/), you want:
CMD /C "CMD /C "git status > c:\some_specific_directory\status.txt 2>&1""